# How to access the React Query `queryClient` outside the provider? e.g. to invalidate queries in Cypress tests

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, react-query

Is it possible to access my app's [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) queryClient outside React?

In my some of my Cypress tests I fetch or mutate some data but then I'd like to invalidate all/part of the queryClient cache afterwards.

Is that possible?

I have tried importing the "same" queryClient that is used in the app, but it doesn't work.

ℹ️ I include these fetch/mutations in my tests merely to allow me to bypass convoluted steps that user's would normally take in the app which already have Cypress tests.

Comment: FYI This has been cross-posted to a discussion on the React Query repo: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/2727

Answer (score 11):

You can add a reference to `queryClient` to window, then invoke it's methods in the test.

From @АлексейМартинкевич example code,

```js
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

if (window.Cypress) {           // only during testing
  window.queryClient = queryClient;
}

export queryClient;
```

In the test

```js
cy.window().then(win => {  // get the window used by app (window in above code)

  win.queryClient.invalidateQueries(...)  // exact same instance as app is using

})
```

I believe that importing will give you a new instance, you must pass a reference to the app's active instance.

---

**Just read your comment** which says exactly this - leaving answer as a code example.

Comment: Thanks we did something similar for Apollo Client

Answer (score 1):

You can store query client as a separate module/global variable. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/global-query-client-demo-1jlmr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth demo, but I believe I am already doing this and it does not work when "outside" the React app. Can you confirm?

When I said: 'I have tried importing the "same" queryClient that is used in the app, but it doesn't work.', this is exactly what I meant.

I have yet to try it, but I think I may need to store the `queryClient` as a property on the `window` object.

Comment: In my demo `useQueryClient() === queryClient`. JS module should only evaluate once, so re-importing should always give the same instance. Also, [QueryClientProvider](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/src/react/QueryClientProvider.tsx) provides the same instance as it receives.
I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. Maybe there is something with environment.