# React Query Invalidation Does Not Trigger Re-Render During Cypress Component Test

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-query

I have a Cypress component test that depends on a React Query invalidation. However, invalidating a query triggers no re-renders during the test. Invalidation works fine when running normally.

Is this a known issue/feature?

@cypress/react: 5.12.4
react: 17.0.2
react-query: 3.34.8

**Update 1**
I found a solution that worked for me here:

[Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344045/how-to-access-the-react-query-queryclient-outside-the-provider-e-g-to-invali)

**Update 2**
I figured out my problem. I wasn't passing the client to QueryClientProvider properly when mounting my component. It's all working well now.